# Errors with tar/split backups

Tags: macos, backup, tar, exfat

I am trying to create backups on an external exFAT disk, but I keep getting errors. I **have to use FAT** (exFAT or FAT32), so my options are very limited. I will need this to backup both macOS and Windows.

My first go-to solution was using `tar` with `split` (1gb file size) on macOS, but I keep getting errors when checking the validity of the backup:

```
% cat Personnel.* | tar tvf -
drwxr-xr-x  0 ab     staff       0 Feb 24 10:58 Personnel/
drwxr-xr-x  0 ab     staff       0 Dec  1 14:02 Personnel/Settings/
-rw-r--r--  0 ab     staff   14340 Feb 24 10:58 Personnel/.DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x  0 ab     staff       0 Jul 26  2021 Personnel/Forms/
tar: Special header too large
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

The command line is with a pipe (`tar cvf - Personnel/ | split -b 1024m - Personnel.`).

I have checked the drive with Disk Utility, but no errors show up.

Sincerely, I have no clue, and google didn't help that much.

Any possible hints?

Comment: Why are you splitting the files at all? You said you have to use "exFAT or FAT32" – _one_ of those has a 4GB file size limit, the other does not.

Comment: @user1686 all files will be uploaded to a cloud storage server, easier with unruly connections than using one big archive.

Comment: It has been a while since I used tar, but it seems like the method that you are using would put the contents of all those files into a single file which is then tar’ed and split. Why use cat at all? Just include the full files themselves, not the file contents, in the tar. Or, better yet, just use rsync and keep all of the files as files, and not inside a tar.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that a tar header entry is too long
( see [tar.c](http://web.mit.edu/freebsd/head/contrib/libarchive/libarchive/archive_read_support_format_tar.c)).

This means that the `cat` command created a bad archive.

It seems that `cat Personnel.*` perhaps included some wrong file.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but I have just now used `cat` with all the file names one by one in order, and I get the same error...

Comment: Somehow, the result of the `cat` is incorrect. Try to `cat` all to one file if you wish to check. I hope that macOS doesn't have a problem with exFAT.

Comment: No, it is not a problem with FAT/exFAT. It turns out, some directories had **custom icons** made with macOS via Finder (copy/paste icons when 
"Get Info" window is open). Well, those are hard links and tar breaks down with that error. I don't know how to update the question now, or even if this can be filed as a bug. Certainly, nowhere Finder told that icons were hard links...

Comment: Right, so it was the `tar cvf` that destroyed the archive, so that the archive in `Personnel.*` files truly contained incorrect header entries.

Comment: I am seeing exactly this behavior when creating a ~100MB tar file on an APFS volume. I'll try to track down what's triggering it.

Comment: @DylanMcNamee similarly for me: I just created the affected file 20m ago on this machine (macOS 12.3.1, x86_64, MBP mid-2015, apfs) using `/usr/bin/tar -> bsdtar`.  I scrolled back and confirmed that creating the 39GB (!) file reported NO errors, and exited 0/success.
Both `-tf` and `-xf` fail with the identical error and extraction stops after restoring 17.9GB (6522 files, 823 dirs)
@harrymc - so the archive isn't necessarily bad/corrupt just too large :'-(

Comment: The file headers might be limited regarding the  offset inside the archive, not enough bits allocated for it.